# how to insert rows when there are none already there only

Tags: c#, windows-server-2008

I have an app and need for deploying to customers. to check in the following way if they have subscribed to the app.

they will have a table on their database. If there are aleady entries in this table, then I can add my modules to it. The record looks like this.

MODULE_ID DESCRIPTION DISPLAY_TEXT ACTIVE
 12               Census           NULL             1

All that I have to do is to add my modules to this in the code. I have 16 and 17 module ID and the names are 'Orders' and 'Missed Medicine'.

Module_ID is len of 18 Numberic

Description is varchar(50)

Display_test varchar(25) allows nulls.

Active is 1 numeric allows nulls.

I need to code the INSERT but only if there are such rows already in the table. what is the best way for this?

Comment: try creating a trigger before insert into the table.
Also edit the subject line to be something meaningful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following:

```
DECLARE @HasData INT

SELECT @HasData = count(*)
FROM [table]

if (@HasData != 0)    
begin
    INSERT INTO [table] VALUES ('module1')
    INSERT INTO [table] VALUES ('module2')
    INSERT INTO [table] VALUES ('module3')
    -- etc
end
```

Answer (score 1):

´SELECT COUNT(*) FROM YourTable;´

If that returns more then 0, you can insert.